# How can we get lmfit parameters after fitting?

Tags: python, windows, parameters, lmfit

I wrote a program to fit some Raman spectra peaks.
I need to return the fitted parameters (position, amplitude, HWHM).

I used the modul lmfit to create a lorentzian peak with constraints.

I have a good agreement between the fitted peak and the raw data according to my figure plot.
But when it comes to exracte the parameters *after* fitting, I have a problem, the programm only return the initial values.

I tied the 'report_fit module' and changing the inital parameter without sucess. The parameters values does not evolve.

What bothers me is that this program works on my colleague's PC but not on mine.
So the problem may comes from my python version.

I am using spyder 2.3.9, and python 3.4 installed with anaconda under windows 10. 
The lmfit module 0.9.3, seems to work partially, since I can get a good fitting agreament (from the figure plt.plot).
But I cannot return the parameter values after fitting.

---

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import factorial
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters  #,report_fit

##############################################################################
# Fit of Raman peaks

def fmin150(pars,x,y):  
    amp= pars['Amp_150'].value
    cent=pars['Cent_150'].value
    hwhm=pars['Wid_150'].value
    a=pars['a_150'].value
    b=pars['b_150'].value
    peak = (amp*hwhm)/(((x-cent)**2)+(hwhm**2)) + ((a*x)+b)
    return peak - y    

def fmin220(pars,x,y):  
    amp= pars['Amp_220'].value
    cent=pars['Cent_220'].value
    hwhm=pars['Wid_220'].value
    a=pars['a_220'].value
    b=pars['b_220'].value
    peak = (amp*hwhm)/(((x-cent)**2)+(hwhm**2)) + ((a*x)+b)
    return peak - y   

def fmin2d(pars,x,y):  
    amp= pars['Amp_2D'].value
    cent=pars['Cent_2D'].value
    hwhm=pars['Wid_2D'].value
    a=pars['a_2D'].value
    b=pars['b_2D'].value
    peak = (amp*hwhm)/(((x-cent)**2)+(hwhm**2))  + ((a*x)+b)
    return peak - y 

##############################################################################
def fit(filename):
    """
    Fit Raman spectrum file
    Return filename, for each peak  (*f*whm, position, height) 
    PL (Position, Intensity, Area)
    """
    print ("----------------------------")
    print("Treating file : ")
    print(filename)
    try:
        data = np.loadtxt(filename)
    except:
        print("Unable to load file")

    xx=data[:,0]
    yy=data[:,1]
 #### Define fitting interval  ##### 
    # Cu oxides (unités en cm-1)
    xminim150 = 120
    xmaxim150 = 170
    xminim220 = 175
    xmaxim220 = 275
    xminim300 = 280
    xmaxim300 = 340
    xminim640 = 345
    xmaxim640 = 800
    # Graphene
    xminimG = 1540
    xmaximG = 1680
    xminim2D = 2600
    xmaxim2D = 2820

    # Definition Baground = place without the fitted peaks
    zone1 = (xx > min(xx)) & (xx < xminim150)
    zone2 = (xx > xmaxim150) & (xx < xminim220)
    zone3 = (xx > xmaxim220) & (xx < xminim300)
    zone4 = (xx > xmaxim300) & (xx < xminim640)
    zone5 = (xx > xmaxim640) & (xx < xminimG)
    zone6 = (xx > xmaximG) & (xx < xminim2D)
    zone7 = (xx > xmaxim2D) & (xx < max(xx))

    x_BG = np.concatenate((xx[zone1],xx[zone2],xx[zone3],xx[zone4],xx[zone5],xx[zone6],xx[zone7]))
    y_BG = np.concatenate((yy[zone1],yy[zone2],yy[zone3],yy[zone4],yy[zone5],yy[zone6],yy[zone7]))


    #Creation de l'interpolation lineaire
    f1 = interp1d(x_BG, y_BG, kind='linear')
    xinterpmin= x_BG[0]   # valeur de x_BG min
    xinterpmax= x_BG[len(x_BG)-1]  # valeur de x_BG max
    nbxinterp = len(xx) * 4 #(nb de point en x)* 4 pour une interpolation correcte

    xnew = np.linspace(xinterpmin, xinterpmax, num=nbxinterp, endpoint=True)
    ynew= f1(xnew)
##########################  Fit 2D peaks  ############################### 
    # create a set of Parameters
    pars150 = Parameters()
    pars220 = Parameters()
    pars300 = Parameters()
    pars640 = Parameters()
    parsg = Parameters()  
    pars2d = Parameters()

            #####   Cu2O pic 150 cm-1     #####
    pars150.add('Amp_150', value=10, min=0.0001, max=100000)  # Amplitude ~intensity
    pars150.add('Cent_150', value=150, min=140, max=160)      # Center  ~position
    pars150.add('Wid_150', value=5, min=4, max=15 )           # Width is the HWHM
    pars150.add('a_150', value=1, min=-100000, max=100000) 
    pars150.add('b_150', value=10, min=-100000, max=100000)
            #####   Cu2O pic 220 cm-1     #####
    pars220.add('Amp_220', value=10, min=0.0001, max=100000)
    pars220.add('Cent_220', value=220, min=200, max=230)
    pars220.add('Wid_220', value=5, min=4, max=15 )
    pars220.add('a_220', value=1, min=-100000, max=100000) 
    pars220.add('b_220', value=10, min=-100000, max=100000)
        #####    Graphene 2D     #####
    pars2d.add('Amp_2D', value=15, min=0.0001, max=100000)
    pars2d.add('Cent_2D', value=2711, min=2670, max=2730)
    pars2d.add('Wid_2D', value=15, min=4, max=25 )
    pars2d.add('a_2D', value=1, min=-100000, max=100000) 
    pars2d.add('b_2D', value=10, min=-100000, max=100000)

    # define x for each peaks
    interv_150 = (xx > xminim150) & (xx < xmaxim150)
    x_150 = xx[interv_150]
    y_150 = yy[interv_150]
    interv_220 = (xx > xminim220) & (xx < xmaxim220)
    x_220 = xx[interv_220]
    y_220 = yy[interv_220]

    interv_2D = (xx > xminim2D) & (xx < xmaxim2D)
    x_2D = xx[interv_2D]
    y_2D = yy[interv_2D]
    ###########################################################
    # Performe FIT with leastsq model  ###########
    result_150 = minimize(fmin150, pars150, args=(x_150, y_150))
    result_220 = minimize(fmin220, pars220, args=(x_220, y_220))
    result_2D = minimize(fmin2d, pars2d, args=(x_2D, y_2D))

    # calculate final result
    final_150 = y_150 + result_150.residual
    final_220 = y_220 + result_220.residual
    final_2D = y_2D + result_2D.residual

    ###########################################################
    # Parameter after fit #
    amp_150= pars150['Amp_150'].value
    cent_150=pars150['Cent_150'].value
    fwhm_150=2*pars150['Wid_150'].value

    amp_220= pars220['Amp_220'].value
    cent_220=pars220['Cent_220'].value
    fwhm_220=2*pars220['Wid_220'].value

    amp_2D= pars2d['Amp_2D'].value
    cent_2D=pars2d['Cent_2D'].value
    fwhm_2D=2*pars2d['Wid_2D'].value

    ###########
    #Plot data#
    plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k+' ,x_150, final_150, 'r', x_220, final_220,'r', x_2D, final_2D,'b')
    plt.xlabel(r'Raman shift (cm$^{-1}$)', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('Intensity (a.u.)', fontsize=14)
    plt.xlim(0,3000)
    plt.title(filename, fontsize=16)
    savename=filename[:-4]+".png"
    print(savename)
    plt.savefig(savename)
    plt.clf()

    return filename, amp_150, cent_150, fwhm_150, amp_220, cent_220, fwhm_220,  amp_2D, cent_2D, fwhm_2D


def main():
    """main program loop"""
    print("----------------------------")
    liste = []
    for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
      if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        liste.append(filename)

    f1 = open("TestFit_all.dat","w")
    header = "Filename\tI_150\tCentre_150\tFWHM_150\tI_220\tCentre_220\tFWHM_220\tI_300\tCentre_300\tFWHM_300\tI_640\tCentre_640\tFWHM_640\tI_G\tCentre_G\tFWHM_G\tI_2D\tCentre_2D\tFWHM_2D\tI_PL\tI_PL_err\tCent_PL\tCent_PL_err\tArea1000_PL\n"
    f1.write(header)
    for i in liste:
        txt=fit(i)
        print(txt)
        #text = str(txt[0])+"\t"+str(txt[1])+"\t"+str(txt[2])+"\t"+str(txt[3])+"\t"+str(txt[4])+"\t"+"\n"
        text = str(txt[0])+"\t"+str(txt[1])+"\t"+str(txt[2])+"\t"+str(txt[3])+"\t"+str(txt[4])+"\t"+str(txt[5])+"\t"+str(txt[6])+"\t"+str(txt[7])+"\t"+str(txt[8])+"\t"+str(txt[9])+"\t"+"\t"+"\n"
        f1.write(text)

    f1.close()

    print("----------------------------")
    print("Done")
###################################################################
# start

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Thank you for you help :)

### [A working fit exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3EyE.png)

Please send your reply to deniz.cakir@etu.umontpellier.fr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script could be a lot shorter to illustrate the question.  But, the final Parameters are held in `result_150.params` and so forth.  The parameters passed into `minimize()` are not altered in the fit.

Well, that's true for lmfit version 0.9.0 and later.  Perhaps your colleague has an older version on lmfit.

Comment: Thank you! 
it worked when I changed: 
    amp_150= pars150['Cent_150'].value
for
    amp_150= result_150.params['Cent_150'].value

Comment: @Deniz Cakir You should accept the answer if it solved your question